# WSO2 IS setting Issuer in SAML Response to "localhost"

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We have a WSO2 Identity Service Provider setup for SAML Inbound Authentication Configuration. However SAML response sent by IS sets Issuer to "localhost" even though we have a different value set in that field

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issuer value in SAML2 SSO response is configured in the Resident IDP configuration of WSO2IS.  In WSO2IS management console, You can go to the `Resident Identity Provider` ->  `SAML2 Web SSO Configuration`  ->  `Identity Provider Entity Id:` In here, you can configure the issuer value.